# ERROR Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am new to spring frame work. I am working on a project and I am facing this error while trying to access the JSP page.

This is my controller class:

```
@Controller
public class LogAdmAction {

    private static final Logger l4j = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    @RequestMapping("/logSubmit.do")
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult errors,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        l4j.debug("admin login start");

        ModelAndView forward = new ModelAndView();
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            forward.setViewName("log-admin");
            return forward;
        }
```

```
This is my relevant JSP code: 

<form:form action="/logSubmit.do" name="loginForm" modelAttribute="loginForm">
```

"LoginForm" is a form bean with the appropriate setter and getters.

The error I am facing while trying to access the JSP page is this: **ERROR Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'loginForm' available as request attribute
**

I tried adding, login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm, thought that would ensure validation and fix the error. Or my understanding is wrong.